# Django legacy database reverse relation not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a database from Django site-1. I'm using the database in Django site-2 using legacy method.

I can create records from site-2.

but I can't use reverse relation serializer to fetch data.

**models.py**

```
class DepartmentCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'department_category'


class DepartmentDesignation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categoryid = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'department_designation'
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DesignationListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = designation
        fields = '__all__'

class CategoryListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    designtion = DesignationListSerializer(source = 'designation_set', many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = category
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
queryset = category.objects.all()

serializer = CategoryListSerializer(queryset, many = True)

return Response(serializer.data)
```

**error**

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `designtion` on serializer `CategoryListSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `DepartmentCategory` instance.
Original exception text was: 'DepartmentCategory' object has no attribute 'designation_set'.
```

I ran the same code in site-1 and its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason the above method didn't work so I added a related_name to the foreignkey field. and used it in the serializer. reverse serializer seems to work now.

below is my edited model and serializer

**model**

```
class DepartmentDesignation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categoryid = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='designtion')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'department_designation'
```

**serializer**

```
class CategoryListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    designtion = DesignationListSerializer(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = category
        fields = '__all__'
```